# Is there a way to find out which function isn't letting Node exit?

Tags: node.js

I'm running a script in NodeJS and the script won't exit. I believe this is because of database connections that are initiated and haven't been closed. Is there a way to list the specific function that isn't letting node exit?

Answer (score 1):

The [why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running) module seems to help here.

Install it temporarily, run your code through it, send it a `SIGUSR1` signal when your program is stuck (the command is shown on stdout at launch) and then it will display everything that is still open.

In my case I wanted to run Jest tests through the module, and use ES6 modules, so the launch command was a bit more complex:

```
NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-vm-modules" npx why-is-node-running ./node_modules/.bin/jest test/mytestfile.test.js
```

Normally you would just run

```
npx why-is-node-running myfile.js
```

For me, it told me that I had forgotten to close a database connection and that's why the code was lingering at exit.